# Error of my android application --GoBang

Tags: android

Here's the simple code of android application--GoBang.However,I cant't solve this error because I am a fresherman.When the application jumps to this activity,it breaks down at once.
Here's the activity code:

```
package org.crazyit.gobang;

import android.app.Activity;    
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;    
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;    
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;    
import android.widget.TextView;    

public class enter extends Activity {    


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */   
     @Override   
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        GobangView gbv; //= new GobangView(this); 
        setContentView(R.layout.acyivity_enter);    


       gbv = (GobangView)this.findViewById(R.id.gobangview);    
       gbv.setTextView((TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.text));    
 }  


public class GobangView extends View{    


    protected int GRID_SIZE = 10;    
    protected int GRID_WIDTH = 30;
    protected int CHESS_DIAMETER = 26;    
    protected int mStartX;    
    protected int mStartY;    

    private Bitmap[] mChessBW;     
    private int[][] mGridArray;   

    boolean key = false;    

    int wbflag = 1;     
    int mLevel = 1;    
    int mWinFlag = 0;    
    private final int BLACK=1;    
    private final int WHITE=2;    

    int mGameState = GAMESTATE_RUN;    
    static final int GAMESTATE_PRE = 0;    
    static final int GAMESTATE_RUN = 1;    
    static final int GAMESTATE_PAUSE = 2;    
    static final int GAMESTATE_END = 3;    

    //private TextView mStatusTextView;     
    public TextView mStatusTextView;    

    private Bitmap btm1;    
    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();    

    CharSequence mText;    
    CharSequence STRING_WIN = "White win! /n Press Fire Key to start new game.";    
    CharSequence STRING_LOSE = "Black win! /n Press Fire Key to start new game.";    
    CharSequence STRING_EQUAL = "Cool! You are equal! /n Press Fire Key to start new    Game.";    

    public GobangView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {    
       super(context, attrs, defStyle);    
    }    

    public GobangView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { 
        super(context, attrs);    
        this.setFocusable(true);  //20090530    
        this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);    

        init();    
   }    



public void init() {    
    mGameState = 1;    
    wbflag = BLACK;    
    mWinFlag = 0; 
    mGridArray = new int[GRID_SIZE-1][GRID_SIZE-1];    

    mChessBW = new Bitmap[2];    

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(CHESS_DIAMETER, CHESS_DIAMETER, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);    
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);    
    Resources r = this.getContext().getResources();    

    Drawable tile = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.bai);    
    tile.setBounds(0, 0, CHESS_DIAMETER, CHESS_DIAMETER);    
    tile.draw(canvas);    
    mChessBW[0] = bitmap;    

    tile = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.hei);    
    tile.setBounds(0, 0, CHESS_DIAMETER, CHESS_DIAMETER);    
    tile.draw(canvas);    
    mChessBW[1] = bitmap;    
 }    


public void setTextView(TextView tv){    
    mStatusTextView =tv;    
    mStatusTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);    
}    

@Override   
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {    
    mStartX = w / 2 - GRID_SIZE * GRID_WIDTH / 2;    
    mStartY = h / 2 - GRID_SIZE * GRID_WIDTH / 2;    
}    

 @Override   
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){    
    switch (mGameState) {    
    case GAMESTATE_PRE:    
        break;    
    case GAMESTATE_RUN: {    
            int x;    
            int y;    
            float x0 = GRID_WIDTH - (event.getX() - mStartX) % GRID_WIDTH;    
            float y0 = GRID_WIDTH - (event.getY() - mStartY) % GRID_WIDTH;    
            if (x0 < GRID_WIDTH / 2) {    
                x = (int) ((event.getX() - mStartX) / GRID_WIDTH);    
            } else {    
                x = (int) ((event.getX() - mStartX) / GRID_WIDTH) - 1;    
            }    
            if (y0 < GRID_WIDTH / 2) {    
                y = (int) ((event.getY() - mStartY) / GRID_WIDTH);    
            } else {    
                y = (int) ((event.getY() - mStartY) / GRID_WIDTH) - 1;    
            }    
            if ((x >= 0 && x < GRID_SIZE - 1)    
                    && (y >= 0 && y < GRID_SIZE - 1)) {    
                if (mGridArray[x][y] == 0) {    
                    if (wbflag == BLACK) {    
                        putChess(x, y, BLACK);    
                        //this.mGridArray[x][y] = 1;     
                        if(checkWin(BLACK)){ //如果是黑棋赢了    
                            mText = STRING_LOSE;    
                            mGameState = GAMESTATE_END;    
                            showTextView(mText);    
                        }else if(checkFull()){//如果棋盘满了    
                            mText = STRING_EQUAL;    
                            mGameState = GAMESTATE_END;    
                            showTextView(mText);    
                        }    

                        wbflag = WHITE;    
                    } else if (wbflag == WHITE) {    
                        putChess(x, y, WHITE);    
                        //this.mGridArray[x][y] = 2;    
                        if(checkWin(WHITE)){    
                            mText = STRING_WIN;    
                            mGameState = GAMESTATE_END;    
                            showTextView(mText);    
                        }else if(checkFull()){//如果棋盘满了    
                            mText = STRING_EQUAL;    
                            mGameState = GAMESTATE_END;    
                            showTextView(mText);    
                        }    
                        wbflag = BLACK;    
                    }    
                }    
            }    
        }    

        break;    
    case GAMESTATE_PAUSE:    
        break;    
    case GAMESTATE_END:    
        break;    
    }    

    this.invalidate();    
    return true;    

}     

@Override   
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg) {    
    Log.e("KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER", " " + keyCode);    

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER){    
        switch(mGameState){    
        case GAMESTATE_PRE:    
            break;    
        case GAMESTATE_RUN:    
            break;    
        case GAMESTATE_PAUSE:    
            break;    
        case GAMESTATE_END:    
        {//游戏结束后，按CENTER键继续    

            Log.e("Fire Key Pressed:::", "FIRE");    
            mGameState = GAMESTATE_RUN;    
            this.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
            this.mStatusTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);    
            this.init();    
            this.invalidate();    


        }    
            break;               
        }    
    }    

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, msg);    
}    

@Override   
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {    

    canvas.drawColor(Color.YELLOW);    

    // 画棋盘    
    {    
        Paint paintRect = new Paint();    
        paintRect.setColor(Color.GRAY);    
        paintRect.setStrokeWidth(2);    
        paintRect.setStyle(Style.STROKE);    

        for (int i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i++) {    
            for (int j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE; j++) {    
                int mLeft = i * GRID_WIDTH + mStartX;    
                int mTop = j * GRID_WIDTH + mStartY;    
                int mRright = mLeft + GRID_WIDTH;    
                int mBottom = mTop + GRID_WIDTH;    
                canvas.drawRect(mLeft, mTop, mRright, mBottom, paintRect);    
            }    
        }    

        //画棋盘的外边框    
        paintRect.setStrokeWidth(4);    
        canvas.drawRect(mStartX, mStartY, mStartX + GRID_WIDTH*GRID_SIZE, mStartY + GRID_WIDTH*GRID_SIZE, paintRect);    
    }    

    //画棋子    

    for (int i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE-1; i++) {    
        for (int j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE-1; j++) {    
            if(mGridArray[i][j] == BLACK){    
                //通过图片来画    
                //canvas.drawBitmap(mChessBW[0], mStartX + (i+1) * GRID_WIDTH - CHESS_DIAMETER/2 , mStartY + (j+1)* GRID_WIDTH - CHESS_DIAMETER/2 , mPaint);    

                //通过圆形来画    
                 {    
                    Paint paintCircle = new Paint();    
                    paintCircle.setColor(Color.BLACK);    
                    canvas.drawCircle(mStartX + (i+1) * GRID_WIDTH, mStartY + (j+1)* GRID_WIDTH, CHESS_DIAMETER/2, paintCircle);    
                }     

            }else if(mGridArray[i][j] == WHITE){    
                //通过图片来画    
                //canvas.drawBitmap(mChessBW[1], mStartX + (i+1) * GRID_WIDTH - CHESS_DIAMETER/2 , mStartY + (j+1)* GRID_WIDTH - CHESS_DIAMETER/2 , mPaint);    

                //通过圆形来画    
                {    
                    Paint paintCircle = new Paint();    
                    paintCircle.setColor(Color.WHITE);    
                    canvas.drawCircle(mStartX + (i+1) * GRID_WIDTH, mStartY + (j+1)* GRID_WIDTH, CHESS_DIAMETER/2, paintCircle);    
                }    
            }    
        }    
    }    
}    

public void putChess(int x, int y, int blackwhite){    
    mGridArray[x][y] = blackwhite;    
}    

public boolean checkWin(int wbflag){    
    for(int i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE - 1 ; i++ ) //i表示列(根据宽度算出来的)    
        for(int j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE - 1; j++){//i表示行(根据高度算出来的)    
            //检测横轴五个相连    
            if(((i+4) < (GRID_SIZE - 1))&&    
               (mGridArray[i][j] == wbflag) && (mGridArray[i+1][j] == wbflag)&& (mGridArray[i + 2][j] == wbflag) && (mGridArray[i + 3][j] == wbflag) && (mGridArray[i + 4][j] == wbflag)){    
                Log.e("check win or loss:", wbflag + "win");    

                mWinFlag = wbflag;    
            }    

            //纵轴5个相连    
            if(((j+4) < (GRID_SIZE - 1))&&    
                       (mGridArray[i][j] == wbflag) && (mGridArray[i][j+1] == wbflag)&& (mGridArray[i ][j+ 2] == wbflag) && (mGridArray[i ][j+ 3] == wbflag) && (mGridArray[i ][j+ 4] == wbflag)){    
                        Log.e("check win or loss:", wbflag + "win");    

                        mWinFlag = wbflag;    
                    }    

            //左上到右下5个相连    
            if(((j+4) < (GRID_SIZE - 1))&& ((i+4) < (GRID_SIZE - 1)) &&    
                       (mGridArray[i][j] == wbflag) && (mGridArray[i+1][j+1] == wbflag)&& (mGridArray[i + 2 ][j+ 2] == wbflag) && (mGridArray[i + 3][j+ 3] == wbflag) && (mGridArray[i + 4 ][j+ 4] == wbflag)){    
                        Log.e("check win or loss:", wbflag + "win");    

                        mWinFlag = wbflag;    
                    }    

            //右上到左下5个相连    
            if(((i-4) >= 0)&& ((j+4) < (GRID_SIZE - 1)) &&    
                       (mGridArray[i][j] == wbflag) && (mGridArray[i-1][j+1] == wbflag)&& (mGridArray[i - 2 ][j+ 2] == wbflag) && (mGridArray[i - 3][j+ 3] == wbflag) && (mGridArray[i - 4 ][j+ 4] == wbflag)){    
                        Log.e("check win or loss:", wbflag + "win");    

                        mWinFlag = wbflag;    
                    }    
    }    

    if( mWinFlag == wbflag){    
        return true;        
    }else   
        return false;    


}    

public boolean checkFull(){    
    int mNotEmpty = 0;    
    for(int i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE -1; i ++)    
        for(int j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE - 1; j ++){    
            if(mGridArray[i][j] != 0) mNotEmpty +=1;    
        }    

    if(mNotEmpty == (GRID_SIZE-1)*(GRID_SIZE-1)) return true;    
    else return false;    
}    

public void showTextView(CharSequence mT){    
    this.mStatusTextView.setText(mT);    
    mStatusTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    

}    

}  
}
```

here's xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">   

<org.crazyit.gobang.GobangView android:id="@+id/gobangview"   
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"     
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />   

<RelativeLayout   
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >   

    <TextView     
        android:id="@+id/text"     
        android:text="hahahhaha"   
        android:visibility="visible"     
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"   
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"     
        android:textColor="#ffff0000"   
        android:textStyle="bold"   
        android:textSize="24sp" >   
     </TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Below is the wrong information:

```
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start       activity ComponentInfo{org.crazyit.gobang/org.crazyit.gobang.enter}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class org.crazyit.gobang.GobangView
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class org.crazyit.gobang.GobangView
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at org.crazyit.gobang.enter.onCreate(enter.java:30)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  ... 11 more
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.crazyit.gobang.GobangView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/org.crazyit.gobang-2.apk]
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
11-28 01:41:28.612: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the `GobangView` class in a new java file

GobangView.java

```
public class GobangView extends View{    
    ....
}
```

enter.java

```
public class enter extends Activity {    
       .....  
}
```

Note: Not yet tried on my own.

Comment: The problem has been solved.But I can't understand why move the GobangView class in a new java file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.crazyit.gobang.GobangView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/org.crazyit.gobang-2.apk]
```

Make sure that you have `GobangView` in the `org.crazyit.gobang` package, it isn't able to find that `Class` right now.